# How to know if the generator is dissipating or generating power?

Tags: power, circuit-analysis

How do I determine whether current/voltage generator is generating or dissipating power. For voltage supply I'm quite sure it depends on current direction, if they are the same, then it's generating. Is it same for current generator, higher voltage on **+**, it's generating, else dissipating?

Edit: DC circuit.

Answer (score 1):

Desperado, you actually asked when a voltage/current source is a source and when - a load. You are right about the voltage source - it becomes a load when the current enters (instead to exit) the positive terminal. This will happen if we connect to it (through a resistor) another voltage source with higher opposite voltage ("+" to "+", and "-" to "-").

It seems, as you noted, that in the case of the current source it is the same... but I think it is not... Usually, a current source consists of a voltage source and a resistor in series.  So it will act as a current source (will pass a current in the same direction) even when we connect a voltage source with opposite polarity... if only it is lower than its internal (excitating) voltage.

From another viewpoint, a current source (and a real voltage source with some internal resistance) always dissipates power in its internal resistor...

Comment: A voltage source with a series resistor is not considered a (ideal) current source. With constant supply voltage and constant load, it can be made to supply a certain amount of current. But it should not be confused with being a current source in standard circuit analysis.

Comment: Yes, we can think of it as of an imperfect current source... what it actually is...

Answer (score 0):

*Edit: Right... I thought that you really had a generator/load kind of situation.. generator as in fill with gasoline, pull the handle, listen to the roar of the engine kind of thing...*

---

Very simple. You need to measure the *Real Power* of the generator/load.

Some theoretic background: There are three power quantities: *Real Power*, *Reactive Power* and *Apparent Power*. Just so that you know they can be measured and calculated for example like this:

- *Real Power* is measured by multiplying instantaneous voltage and current samples and calculating RMS.
- *Apparent Power* is measured by multiplying the average RMS voltage with average RMS current.
- *Reactive Power* can be calculated mathematically from the Real Power and Apparent Power, and the sign (whether it's Inductive or Capacitive) is determined from whether the voltage is leading or lagging the current.

In your case you just need the Real Power, so it's very simple. Measure the current in the wire from/to the generator using a current transformer. Also measure the voltage. So that you don't need to worry about the sampling theorem, sample them at a relatively high sample rate, 1 KHz or more. For accurate results, you either need samples from an exact integer number of waves (60Hz or 50Hz) or a long(ish) period of time. If you know what *windowing* means, use a Hann Window. If not, then just don't worry about windowing.

Multiply the instantaneous current samples with same-time voltage samples. Then calculate RMS. The result is the Real Power, in Watts if your sampling period is one second. If it's positive then the circuit is using power. If it's negative then the circuit is generating power.

If the unit is three phase, no problem, just measure the phases separately and add the final RMS values of the three phases together.

**Be careful with the polarity of the current transformers**: changing the polarity will change the sign of the result. Experiment with a known resistive load (electric heater element etc) to verify that you get the correct amount of watts from your measurement circuit.

If you don't need the information so accurately, you can just measure the current x voltage pairs, and keep a running average to know if it's positive or negative.

There are also power meter (KWh-meter) ICs available which may simplify the task.

Answer (score 0):

In standard circuit analysis, the convention is that for any device, if the current flow from the terminal with relatively positive voltage internally to its negative terminal, then it is absorbing power. This is true for any type of device, voltage source, current source, resistor, capacitor or any arbitrary circuit. For a current source, it is an idealized device, we can't say whether the absorbed power is dissipated, stored or extracted. For a real device like a resistor, the power is dissipated. For a capacitor, the power is stored...